# Cakephp 2.2 public no login, admin must login

Tags: cakephp, authentication

I am using the auth component. I have setup my route to accommodate admin prefix.

The entire site insists on logging in. I only want admin_* pages to validate login which it does. But the other non prefixed pages such as index, hospitalist, etc needs to be accessed as normal public viewers or visitors.

How does one set up the appController for this? It's been frisking me out for a week now.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: can you post your Auth settings ?

Answer (score 0):

This is covered in great detail in the book, and under "[Simple Authentication and Authorization Application](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html)".

In the future, please look at the [CakePHP book](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/index.html) and post what you've tried.  It will everyone involved. :)